# WooCommerce: Display product categories to make IF statement

Tags: php, categories, woocommerce-offtopic

Depending on the product category, I have different data to display on category page. I'm getting my category `ID` this way:

```
<?php global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
    break;
}

if ($product_cat_id == "6") {
echo "aaa";
}
elseif ($product_cat_id == "7") {
echo "bbb";
}
?>
```

But I need to display different data when product is in two categories and it does not work.

```
echo $product_cat_id;
```

It recognizes only one category. How do I make it recognize two and make `IF` statement for product which is in category 6 `AND` 7?

Answer (score 1):

> Try This Code

```
        <?php global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
        break;
    }

    if ($product_cat_id == "6" && $product_cat_id == "7" ) {
    echo "aaabbb";
    }
 else if ($product_cat_id == "6"  ) {
    echo "aaa";
    }
    else if ($product_cat_id == "7") {
    echo "bbb";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$product_cat_id` is an `array()` of all of your categories and it looks like you are only running the `if` statement outside of the array to check the category's ID. Instead, you should run it inside the `foreach` loop. This is untested, but it should look something like this:

```
<?php
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
    break;
}

foreach ( $product_cat_id as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $value == "6" ) {
        echo "aaa";
    }
    if ( $value == "7" ) {
        echo "bbb";
    }
}
?>
```